# MVC Kendo Grid with custom popup editor using MultiSelect - can't get selected items in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc, multi-select

The title says it all.

POPUP FORM:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@using Batc.AgileApp.Web.Areas.ProductReuse.Models
@model BomViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BomId)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Row)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserWorkSessionId)


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
            <span>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductClass)
            </span>
            <br/>@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductClass)
                       .DataTextField("Text")
                       .DataValueField("Value")
                       .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:125px"})
                       .DataSource(source =>
                       {
                           source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetDropDownLookups", "AjaxProductReuse", new {id = "ProductClass"}); });
                       })
                       )
            <div style="font-weight: normal;">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductClass)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
            <span>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProgramSelectedList)
            </span>

            @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m.ProgramSelectedList)
                  .Placeholder("Select program...")
                  .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:200px"})
                  .DataSource(source =>
                  {
                      source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetLookups", "AjaxProductReuse", new {id = "Program"}); });
                  })
                  )
            <div style="font-weight: normal;">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProgramSelectedList)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

GRID FORM (cshtml view):

```
@using Batc.AgileApp.Web.Areas.ProductReuse.Models
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model AssemblyViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("Assembly", "ProductReuse", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "frmStartScreen"}))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Status)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserWorkSessionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GlobalPartNum)

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<BomViewModel>()
          .Name("bom-prGrid-kendoGrid")
          .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "prGrid"})
          .ClientRowTemplate("")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Edit()).Width(80);
              columns.Bound(g => g.BomId).Hidden();
              columns.Bound(g => g.IsEditable).Hidden();
              columns.Bound(g => g.Row).Width(75).Title("Row");
              columns.Bound(p => p.Program).Width(100).Title("Program");
              columns.Bound(p => p.ProductClass).Width(100).Title("Product<br/>Class");
              columns.Bound(p => p.ResponsibleEng).Width(120).Title("Resp Eng");
              columns.Bound(p => p.ProjectNum).Width(100).Title("Project<br/>No");
              columns.Bound(p => p.AccessControl).Width(150).Title("Access Control");
          })
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .Model(model => { model.Id(g => g.BomId); })
              .PageSize(100)
              .Read(r => r.Action("GetCloneAssembly", "AjaxProductReuse").Data("ProductReuseGridReadData"))
              .Update(u => u.Action("UpdateBomItem", "AjaxProductReuse").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
              .Events(e => e.Error("ajax_error").Sync("dataSource_sync").Change("dataSource_change"))
          )
          .Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound").Edit("onEdit"))
          .Pageable(pager => pager
              .Input(true)
              .Numeric(true)
              .Info(true)
              .PreviousNext(true)
              .Refresh(true)
              .PageSizes(new int[] {100, 250, 500, 1000})
          )
          .Sortable()
          .Scrollable()
          .Filterable()
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("BOMForm").Window(w => w.Title("Manage BOM Item").Name("BOMForm"))) 
          .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true)).Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
          )
}
```

Model (properties of interest):

```
[MetadataType(typeof(BomViewModelMetaData))]
public class BomViewModel: BomModel
{
    public int BomId { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int UserWorkSessionId { get; set; }
    public string ProductClass { get; set; }
    public string Program { get; set; }
    public List<string> ProgramSelectedList { get { return Program.ToList(); } set { Program = value.ToDelimitedString(); } }

}
```

My (ajax) controller looks like:

```
public JsonResult UpdateBomItem([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, BomViewModel bomViewModel)   // [Bind(Prefix = "models")]
{
    var command = _mapper.Map<BomModel>(bomViewModel);
    var commandResponse = _productReuseService.UpdateBomItem(command);
    var response = _mapper.Map<List<BomViewModel>>(commandResponse);
    return Json(ToDataSourceResult(response, request, modelState: ModelState));
}
```

The problem I am encountering is the data being posted to my controller.  It looks like this in fiddler (where the first 3 items map to the first object in the controller, the remainder being the model):

```
sort=
&group=
&filter=
&Program=PROGRAM_ORIGINAL
&ProgramSelectedList[0]=PROGRAM_01
&ProgramSelectedList[1]=PROGRAM_02
&UserWorkSessionId=45
&Row=10
&ProductClass=1
&BomId=151927
```

What I expected was:

```
sort=
&group=
&filter=
&Program=PROGRAM_01, PROGRAM_02
&ProgramSelectedList=PROGRAM_01
&ProgramSelectedList=PROGRAM_02
&UserWorkSessionId=45
&Row=10
&ProductClass=1
&BomId=151927
```

Is there a "special" setting in Kendo or JQuery or .NET to make this list behave correctly?  I currently am using Kendo in MVC HTML Helper mode only.  This means I have almost no JS propping up my desired actions on the UI side of things.

This is an internal LOB app, low usage, minimal users.

Comment: Your property `ProgramSelectedList` is typeof `List<string>` so it should be `&ProgramSelectedList[0]=PROGRAM_01` in order to bind (i.e. with the indexers. Why would you want it to be without them? I'm guessing your problem is something to do with the odd `get/set` you have in that property. It should be just `public List<string> ProgramSelectedList { get; set; }` (and then in the controller methods, you can convert to and from the `Program` property)

Comment: MVC model binder does not understand the array notation properly.  It is expecting $param=value1&param=value2&param=valueN.

Comment: Of course it understands. That's the default ValueProvider for collections unless the content type is set to json.

Comment: That may be an underlying problem then.  Since the return type is marked as JsonResult rather than ActionResult, does that mean the model binder is expecting JSON?

Comment: That should not make a difference. I'm assuming now that this is an issues with Kendo Grid, but I don't know enough about the way it serializes its data to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging and frustration the answer is pretty simple.  I needed to add a JS helper to put the data into a format the MVC Model Binder could understand.

```
<script>
    function getUpdatedBomRowData() {
        var program = $("#ProgramSelectedList").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString();
        return {
            program: program
        }
    }
</script>
```

And then on the grid's datasource update action I added a Data(...) method:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => { model.Id(g => g.BomId); })
    .PageSize(100)
    .Read(r => r.Action("GetCloneAssembly", "AjaxProductReuse").Data("ProductReuseGridReadData"))
    .Update(u => u.Action("UpdateBomItem", "AjaxProductReuse").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("getUpdatedBomRowData"))
    .Events(e => e.Error("ajax_error").Sync("dataSource_sync").Change("dataSource_change"))
)
```

The JS will then put a comma delimited string into the Program property before sending to the controller.  Since Program is being used as (A) a DB representation of the table field, and (B) a backing field for List ProgramSelectedList, my code seems to be happy now.

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to display the "in progress" spinner on the popup form when the user submits the (popup) form.  <bleh/>

Comment: To show a spinner on the popup, you can use the `requestStart` and `requestEnd` events of the grid's dataSource.